# How to install oauth2-helper?

Tags: 18.04, oauth

I need to install oauth2-helper on Ubuntu 18.04. Any idea how to do this? I looked for directions.I am having trouble getting a token back from Google OAuth2, and I am hoping to ensure that my code is not causing the issue.

Comment: Please clarify you release of Ubuntu. There was no release in 2018-February (18.02)

Comment: sorry I meant 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to install Postman instead. This seems to do the same thing, which is what I need.